# Parsing response based on ResponseHeaders

Tags: angular, angular-services

When making a `http.get()` to a REST API, metadata concerning page, page-count and total results are often returned in response headers.

Angular's `HttpClient` parses and returns data based on the `response.body`, and returns it in an Observable.

How then do you query the Response headers, and call the getter recursively until you've received the full dataset from the REST API?

Or do you build you own HttpClient using basic AJAX methods?

Comment: See https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response for how to access the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
this._myService.getDocument(item.ID)
    .subscribe(
        (data) => {
            this.doSomething(data);
        },
        error => { this.errorMessage = <any>error; },
        () => { });


doSomething(data: HttpResponse<any>) {
        let count = data.headers.get('count');
        console.log(count);
    }
```